# wso2 - check if a sequence really exists

Tags: templates, wso2, sequence, exists

I have this scenario in esb wso2:

- a variable stored in a registry called Version
- s1 -> is a sequence of version1
- s2 -> is a sequence of version2
- serror -> is a sequence in case of error

If Version == 1 then s1 is called
If Version == 2 then s2 is called
If Version is empy s3 is called

Now the issue is: if Version == 3 I got this error:

```
Sequence named Value {name ='null', expression =get-property('seqName')} cannot be found
```

Beacuse the s3 doesn't exist

My question is: is it a way to check if a sequence really exists?

Thank you!

Regards
Claudio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way to check the existence of a sequence through existing mediators. If you really need to do that, you can write a class mediator and check the synapseConfiguration object. But for your case, you can use a switch mediator and add a default case with a default sequence to notify that the request has a not supported version.

```
<Switch>
<Case 1>
<Seq1>
<Case 2>
<Seq2>
<Case default>
<SeqDefault>
</Switch>
```

Comment: Hi Chanaka, could you please help me about how to write a class mediator? which are the steps to follow? many thanks

Comment: You can refer the following link to write a class mediator for WSO2 ESB. http://soatutorials.blogspot.com/2013/08/10-minute-tutorial-for-extending-wso2.html

Comment: Thank you! I'll let you know!